How can I move gridded SVG single elements to a curvilinear distorsion disposition?
I have a svg with gridded single elements and I need to move/rotate all of them creating a curvilinear distortion disposition.

I could do it rasterizing the image, but I need to keep vectorial and separated single elements.
Is there any solution to this problem?
I tried many vectorial software but I didn't find any tool for it.

You can do this atleast in illustrator with the envelope distort tool

You can probably approximate it with a carefully made feDisplacementMap. This tool might help

You can do it in Inkscape (which is free) with a Bend live path effect. First group all the objects, then in the Live Path Effects, apply a Bend effect. Choose the Nodes tool. Click on the Edit on Canvas button in the Bend effect panel, and click and drag the path to bend it.


When you export this, does it use a filter or does it actually change the paths used?

@ZachSaucier You can flatten the effect - there's a dropdown in the path effects, where you can choose "flatten". Or alternatively just do Path > Object to Path, which is similar to Expand in Illustrator.

So if you don't flatten it, it uses a transform or filter? I think that's what the OP is looking for if I'm understanding them correctly

@ZachSaucier No, this isn't an SVG filter or a transform.  It's Inkscape's own built in Live Path Effect functionality, which is non-destructive.  Inkscape maintains a copy of the altered paths in the SVG, as well as the original (if saved as an Inkscape SVG).  If you save as a plain SVG, all the Inkscape specific XML is removed, and everything just becomes paths (like expanding in Illustrator).
